# Active Directory Mapped Drive won't stay connected

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, mac-osx-server, mappeddrive

WinSrv08R2. I have a drive mapped to Win7 clients via Group Policy that's on another computer (an OS X server, mapped via "\serverIP\folder"). EVERY time the user logs out and then back in, it pops up "Could not reconnect all network drives", except the two other mapped drives (from the Srv08 machine) stay connected. This is after you put in login info after clicking on the OS X Mapped Drive from My Computer and check REMEMBER MY CREDENTIALS, yet log off and back on (or reboot) and it does it all over again, and you have to re-enter the credentials every time.

Any solutions?

Better explanation:

1. Drive Maps via Group Policy on Server 08 R2, maps three drives (two local to server08, one via "\\serverIP\folder"), which is an OS X server.
2. Windows 7 computer is part of the Server08's domain and receives drive maps at User Login.
3. The two drives local to the Win08 Server connect fine EVERY time.
4. The drive from the OS X server can't connect and asks for credentials EVERY logout/login and
   reboot, even though Win7 checkbox set to Remember Credentials.